# How to display checkboxes with checked by default?

Tags: spring-mvc, checkbox

I am using form to display the checkboxes in my jsp page.In below "data" is the Map object.

```
<form:checkboxes id="test" path="test" items="data/>
```

How to display all the checkboxes by default checked?

Comment: if you add CHECKED right before /> closing will it work? so items="data" CHECKED/>

Comment: @FeRtoll no it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/) for some example

From the link:

```
<form:checkboxes items="${dynamic-list}" path="property-to-store" />
```

> For multiple checkboxes, as long as the
>   “path” or “property” value is equal to
>   any of the “checkbox values –
>   ${dynamic-list}“, the matched checkbox
>   will be checked automatically.